# Representing a function $f$ as difference of two increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my question and I would be really gratified if anyone helps!

Let us enumerate all rational points on $[0,1]$ as $Q\cap [0,1]=\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ and define the function $f$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $x=r_n, n=1,2,...$ and $0$ otherwise. 
(1) Is it possible to represent $f$ as difference of two increasing functions $g,h$. If so, give an example of these two functions.
(2) How about for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ with the same domain as previous.

for the (1), function $f$ is a decreasing function on $[0,1]$ so it is of bounded variation function, and hence it can be written as $h-g$ as difference of two increasing functions using Jordan decomposition theorem. 
It would be appreciated if anyone can confirm my solution and of course makes it correct if it is wrong. I also need help in constructing the functions.

Many thanks friends!

Comment: No, your solution isn't correct. Why did you decide that $f$ is decreasing? It isn't.

Comment: As @zipirovich  said, $f$ is not decreasing. (If it were, then you could take $g=-f$ and $h=0$ to get $f=h-g$.) Fortunately, though, your first $f$ is of bounded variation, because $\sum_n(1/n^2)$ converges.  So this $f$ can still be expressed as the difference of two increasing functions. For the second $f$, on the other hand, you can show that it's not of bounded variation because $\sum_n(1/n)$ diverges.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks a lot for replying to my question. You are right it is not decreasing. How about choosing $g$ and $h$? I can take one of them as $0$ but how about the other one? Moreover, about (2), as it is not bounded variation can not express it as difference of two increasing functions?

Comment: You cannot take either of them as $0$, because your f$ is neither increasing nor decreasing. As for the second, do you know the theorem that the difference of two increasing functions is always of bounded variation? If so, apply it; if not, try to prove it (and then apply it).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes your completely right. I know the theorem. Hence, we can not express it as difference of two increasing functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andreas_Blass wrote the first function has bounded variation. The standard way to write $f$ as difference of two increasing functions is to compute the pointwise variation  of $f$ in $[0,x]$, which gives 
$$V_f(x)=\sum_{n:\, r_n\le x}\frac1{n^2}$$ and then to write 
$$f(x)=V_f(x)-(V_f(x)-f(x)).$$
The function $V_f$ is increasing and so is the function  $V_f-f$.
The other function you wrote does not have finite pointwise variation and so it cannot be written as difference of increasing functions. Indeed, the space of functions of bounded variations on, say $[0,1]$, is the smallest vector space that contains all monotone functions. In particular, any difference of increasing functions would have finite pointwise variation and your function does not.

Comment: Thanks @Gio67 for complete and informative answer!